# How can I erase (or hide) pencil marks from a document with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to erase pencil marks on a printed document.

The original image:
[image: orig]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def remove_pencil_marks(image_path):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Threshold the grayscale image to create a binary mask of pencil marks
    _, pencil_mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Create a copy of the original image
    result = image.copy()

    # Set the pixel values in the result image to white (255) where the pencil mask is white
    result[pencil_mask == 255] = [255, 255, 255]
    
    kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
    result = cv2.filter2D(result, -1, kernel)

    return result


# Input image path
input_image_path = '/Users/injoonoh/Downloads/IMG_A6915DF7F69C-1.jpeg'

# Remove pencil marks
output_image = remove_pencil_marks(input_image_path)

cv2.imshow('image1', output_image)
while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result
[image: res]

How should I edit my code to erase the pencil marks better?

Or, would there be an another approach that has better results?

Also, if both is not possible, is there a way to just hide the pencil marks? (with rectangles, etc...)

Comment: Use adaptive threshold. It should be better, but will not be perfect, since the pencil marks are nearly the same darkness as your printed text